# ReactJS installed on production server

Tags: reactjs

Okay here is the just of the situation

1. My company has a website that has a mega menu built with ReactJS
2. The content manager wants to be able to edit the menu without a developer
3. They did not like my solution (rebuilding the menu to use a database) saying it would take too much time
4. They outsourced the job and this developer says he has built a ReactJS admin tool but he needs ReactJS installed on the production server.  His admin tool would automatically build the production build and move the contents of the build folder to the correct location.

I'm not an expert (by any means) but this sounds crazy to me.  Has anyone ever installed ReactJS on a production server?

Comment: I think you need to ask the developer who this was outsourced to exactly what he means by "needs ReactJS installed on the production server". It's not easy for anyone on Stack Overflow to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
He needs ReactJS on the server and here is his explanation:
"The Admin tool replicates and automates the steps usually taken by developer(having ReactJS installed in local machine); it needs to be deployed in a server having ReactJS installed. So it can build the final files at runtime, which will be FTPed to Beta/Prod servers of the website to populate the change."

Comment: Alright. If he can FTP to the beta/prod servers, then he can also FTP his entire React app that already contains the React and ReactDOM dependencies, so I don't understand where he is coming from.